# Как загружать список валют с сайта ЦБ https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js

Tags: java

Мне необходимо в загрузить список валют с сайта ЦБ [www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js](http://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js) и отобразить его в виде списка, объясните пожалуйста как это делается.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Получить список валют можно в два этапа:

1. Получить `JSON` с API ЦБ при помощи класса `URL`.
2. Разобрать получившийся `JSON` при помощи библиотек, например `org.json`.

Рабочий пример (использовались библиотеки `org.json` и `com.google.code.gson`):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        // Преобразует массив байт в строку.
        String json = new String(
            // Создаёт URL со ссылкой на API ЦБ.
            new URL("https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js")
                // Открывает поток получения данных.
                .openStream()
                // Считывает все данные в виде массива байт.
                .readAllBytes()
       );

       // Парсит JSON и получает данные валют.
       JSONObject currenciesData = new JSONObject(json)
           .getJSONObject("Valute");

      // Получает коды валют из полученных данных.
      List<Currency> currencies = currenciesData.keySet()
          // Преобразовывает Set в Stream.
          .stream()
          // При помощи GSON переводит JSON строчку валюты к классу Currency.
          .map((currency) ->
              new Gson().fromJson(
                  currenciesData.getJSONObject(currency)
                      .toString(),
                  Currency.class
              )
          )
          // Преобразовывает Stream в List.
          .toList();

        // Выводит информацию в консоль.
        currencies.forEach((currency) ->
            System.out.println(currency.Name + " (" + currency.CharCode + ") - " + currency.Value)
        );
    } catch (Exception ignored) { }
}

// Класс с необходимыми нам данными из полученного JSON.
static class Currency {
    String CharCode;
    String Name;
    double Value;
}
```

*Не забывайте отмечать правильный ответ решением, нажимая на галочку, это так же помогает отвечающим :3*